# GWT method returns before RequestBuilder ajax call finishes

Tags: java, ajax, gwt

here's my code so far (this is using GWT):

```
private ArrayList<tObjects> getSuggestions(String query)
{
    // Clear previous suggestions
    Window.alert("Clearing arraylist");
    arrayList.clear();
    query = query.toUpperCase().replace(" ", "");

    RequestBuilder rb = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, "xmlfile.php?query="+query);
    rb.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    try
    {
        rb.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback()
        {

            @Override
            public void onResponseReceived(com.google.gwt.http.client.Request request, com.google.gwt.http.client.Response response)
            {
                Window.alert(response.getText());

                    // Do a lot of data processing here.
                    Window.alert("Adding to arraylist");
                    addToArrayList(data);


                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(com.google.gwt.http.client.Request request, Throwable exception)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }
    catch(RequestException e)
    {
        Window.alert(e.toString());
    }
    Window.alert("Returning arraylist. "+arrayList.toString());
    return arrayList;
}
```

I receive the response correctly, but the method returns the (empty) arrayList before it is added. If i remove the arrayList.clear(), on the next ajax call I see the result of the previous call. When I look at the alerts, the fire in this order:

1) "Clearing arrayList."

2) "Returning arrayList."

3) Alert with correct response from ajax

4) "Adding to arrayList"

It seems like the method is not waiting for the ajax to complete before returning and finishing the method. How can I make it wait for the ajax & population of the arrayList before I get to the return statement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Async calls means non-blocking code! You have to think *asynchronously*, e.g., never rely on method that should return something that is retrieved using an async call: design your application to *do not wait for data*, but *wait for responses*.

Generally this is done by putting the logic inside the `onResponseReceived()` method, or passing-in a callback that will be called, or using an event.

Answer (score 0):

[AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) stands for Asynchronous Javascript And XML

You request builder is doing an asynchronous call. It means that the method which does the server call will always return just after you sent your request, BEFORE your answer will come back.

In your example

```
rb.sendRequest
```

will return almost instantly, before having received the response.

This is why you are passing callbacks methods as parameters (onResponseReceived method and onError method). The callbacks will be called once your request has been treated by the server and your answer has been sent back to your client.

Now if you want to execute something after your callback method has been called (once you have received your array), you can/should use events. In your callback method `onResponseReceived` you can fire and event, for example ArrayListReceived. You listen for that event in your class or any other class sharing the same eventbus and do what ever you want to do with that array.

That's why event bus are so useful.

By the way, you should not try to make synchronous calls in a web application as it would freeze your client while waiting for the answer. As Javascript is mono-threaded (I do not know is web workers are yet supported in GWT) there is no way to continue any processing while waiting for a call to return if you are using synchronous method.